# Android keystore bug

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, keystore, apache-cordova

I am a beginner in Android development. I have created an Apache Cordova app in Visual Studio and for publishing it I need to generate a keystore. I followed the steps at - https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/.

It goes all smoothly till the place in cmd where the info such as password, name ,etc is asked. I keep typing but nothing is accepted. I even tried copying and pasting but still it didn't work.

Here's the screenshot:- 
[image]

I am a web developer trying to create Android apps and am really a beginner in Android development and not an adept so plz help me out.

Comment: even though nothing shows the password is still there, its not a bug

Comment: @tyczj The "Enter password" thing is coming but I am not able to type anything into the command prompt

Comment: did you read what I wrote? I said it is still there. your typing is not shown for security

Answer (score 0):

Even though the words don't appear as you're typing, they are still being accepted. As mentioned in the comments, this is for security reasons. If you type the password you want to use, and then press Enter, your password will bet set.